# Please what does (PDOException $e) and PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode()) mean in simplest terms?

Tags: php, exception, pdo

Can you please explain what (PDOException $e) and PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode()) does and mean here?

```
try
  {
    $pdo = new PDO($attr, $user, $pass, $opts);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
    throw new PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
  }
```

Comment: It means the `catch` will only catch exceptions which are of the type `PDOException` specifically - it will not catch other exceptions. And the `throw` just creates a new Exception and causes a new crash, using the same message and code as the exception it's just caught. So actually this is pretty pointless, I don't know why anyone would write it like that. Catching and re-throwing with the same information does not achieve anything useful.

Comment: @ADyson ...other than erasing the stack trace and therefore ditching the credentials from the error message

Comment: @YourCommonSense well that's a possibility. Arguably PDO shouldn't output that info in the exception anyway...

Comment: @ADyson it is not PDO, the stack trace is collected from the entire execution path. this is how exceptions work. For the exception, it doesn't matter whether some variable passed to some function, being a password or not

Comment: @YourCommonSense Depending on the problem, you'll still potentially get something like the mysql `Access denied for user ... xxxx` message even in that case. So it might only partially obscure the credentials. And it just makes it more difficult to debug. Surely a better solution is to make sure no-one who shouldn't can access the PHP log file.

Comment: @ADyson I agree. I myself find this measure controversial. But for the inexperienced people I find it acceptable tradeoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start is [the PHP manual page on Exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Exceptions are a mechanism of *mandatory error handling* - rather than setting a flag that subsequent code must actively check, throwing an exception aborts all running code until it reaches a matching `catch` block. If no `catch` block is found, the entire script exits.

`catch` blocks match using the same logic as [the `instanceof` operator](https://www.php.net/instanceof) - you name a class or interface, and the exception must be the same class, a sub-class, or implement that interface. You then give a variable name - in your example `$e`, but it can be any name you like - and PHP assigns the exception to that variable and runs the content of the `catch` block.

*Creating* an exception is the same as creating any other object - you use the `new` operator. Once created, they can have properties and methods, including a default set which includes `getMessage()` and `getCode()`, which return values which were passed when originally constructed. Their special behaviour happens when you use the `throw` keyword.

So, the code you've shown:

1. Runs some code that might throw an exception (`new PDO(...)`)
2. Catches any exception matching `instanceof PDOException`
3. Looks up the "message" and "code" on that exception object
4. Creates a new `PDOException` object
5. Throws that new exception

The result on its own is pretty much useless - in particular, steps 4 and 5 can be replaced by `throw $e`, which essentially means "I've looked at this exception, but decided it's still a problem; carry on looking for another matching `catch` block". That's occasionally useful if you want to do something between steps 3 and 4, such as logging or cleanup.

As [pointed out in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71648229/157957) it does remove the backtrace, which might otherwise expose credentials. That would be better handled by setting [zend.exception_ignore_args=true](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.exception-ignore-args) in your PHP configuration. PHP 8.2 will also have [a new facility that automatically hides certain parameters in backtraces](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/redact_parameters_in_back_traces).

Answer (score 2):

Let's compare the output of this code with and without try catch

```
$pdo = new PDO('foo', 'username', 'password');
```

will give us

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct():
> Argument #1 ($dsn) must be a valid data source name in pdo.php:6
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\SERVER\www\htdocs\pdo.php(6): PDO->__construct('foo', **'username'**, **'password'**)
> #1 {main} thrown in pdo.php on line 6

notice the username and password can be seen in the error message

Now with try catch and re-throw

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('foo', 'username', 'password');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    throw new PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

the output will be

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): 
Argument #1 ($dsn) must be a valid data source name in pdo.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in pdo.php on line 12
```

as you can see, there is no username or password.

This is the only reason such a clumsy code is employed

Comment: Thank you so much for breaking it down for me this way. The try . . . catch pair of commands was to achieve a secure way of checking for error. I appreciate it. Is there a better way to achieve this than the "clumsy code"? What does the $e mean or I shouldn't worry about it?

Comment: $e is Exception itself. You may want to read about exceptions in general. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.catch

Comment: I don't know the better way. Like it was said in the comments, another way would be to make sure that errors aren't displayed and the error logs are secure

Comment: It's worth noting that you can keep the backtrace but not the arguments by setting [zend.exception_ignore_args=true](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.exception-ignore-args) in your PHP configuration. PHP 8.2 will also have [a new facility that redacts certain parameters in backtraces](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/redact_parameters_in_back_traces).